# Remove padding around alert dialog

Tags: android, dialog, padding, alert

I use AlertDialog.Builder to make a custom dialog using these instructions:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

It works, but my view is inside a black box (the standard dialog frame). This box has **padding** around its edges, so i cant make it use the full display width.

How can I get rid of the padding? I fetched the layoutparams after the dialog is displayed, and changed all the parameters and flags, nothing helped.

When someone else asked this here on SO, the answer was

```
builder.setView(dialogView, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

but as far as I see, this method doesnt exist, only setView(dialogView).

Comment: Found any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It's not builder.setView
You need to create an instance of the dialog first:

```
Dialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.setView(dialogView, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way to do this is to use the base (or extended) Dialog class and setView to set a custom view.

You'll also have to add your own buttons and handle them accordingly.

Comment: I am using setView with an inflated layout.

Comment: I meant you'll have to create your own Dialog class by extending Dialog and not use AlertDialog.builder.

Comment: this answer did work for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63993190/alertdialog-remove-unnecessary-space

Answer (score 0):

If just want to get rid of the black borders, you can invert the color by:

```
setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
```

But thats not a correct solution, it is just to get rid of the black borders wich some people have asked for.

Regards