# AlertDIalog Remove unnecessary space

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I display the AlertDialog in custom position with a custom layout.

When I display my alert dialog I am getting more white space on the right side of the view even though my custom layout does not have that white space.

I follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767895/how-to-set-alertdialog-custom-title-top-margin-and-remove-unwanted-padding/39768076) did not get much help

Please check the attached image for details

[image]

Here is my **custom_obstacle_dialog.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/toggle"
            android:checked="true"
            android:textOff="Camera"
            android:textOn="Camera" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/toggle"
            android:checked="true"
            android:textOff="Lidar"
            android:textOn="Lidar" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/toggle"
            android:checked="true"
            android:textOff="Sonar"
            android:textOn="Sonar" />

    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my Alert Dialog

```
    final AlertDialog.Builder obstacleDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.CustomDialog);
                obstacleDialogBuilder.setMessage(null);

                LayoutInflater inflaterObstacle = this.getLayoutInflater();
                View obstacleDialogView = inflaterObstacle.inflate(R.layout.custom_obstacle_dialog, null);
                obstacleDialogBuilder.setView(obstacleDialogView);

                cameraButton = (ToggleButton) obstacleDialogView.findViewById(R.id.one);
                lidarButton = (ToggleButton) obstacleDialogView.findViewById(R.id.two);
                sonarButton = (ToggleButton) obstacleDialogView.findViewById(R.id.three);

                SharedPreferences app_resources = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("App_Resources", MODE_PRIVATE);
                boolean obsCamera = app_resources.getBoolean("ObsCamera", true);
                boolean obsLidar = app_resources.getBoolean("ObsLidar", true);
                boolean obsSonar = app_resources.getBoolean("ObsSonar", true);

                cameraButton.setChecked(obsCamera);
                lidarButton.setChecked(obsLidar);
                sonarButton.setChecked(obsSonar);

                if (obsSonar && ultrasonicStatus)
                    sonarButton.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.red_rounded_button));

                if (obsLidar && lidarStatus)
                    lidarButton.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.red_rounded_button));

                if (obsCamera && cameraStatus)
                    cameraButton.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.red_rounded_button));

                cameraButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("App_Resources", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                        editor.putBoolean("ObsCamera", isChecked);
                        editor.apply();

                        obstacleDetection.cameraDetectioin(isChecked);

                    }
                });

                lidarButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("App_Resources", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                        editor.putBoolean("ObsLidar", isChecked);
                        editor.apply();

                        obstacleDetection.lidarDetectioin(isChecked);

                    }
                });

                sonarButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("App_Resources", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                        editor.putBoolean("ObsSonar", isChecked);
                        editor.apply();

                        obstacleDetection.ultrasonicDetectioin(isChecked);

                    }
                });


                obstacleAlertDialog = obstacleDialogBuilder.create();

                obstacleAlertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                obstacleAlertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.SlideUpDownAnimation;
                WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = obstacleAlertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();

                wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;
                wmlp.x = 100;   //x position
                wmlp.y = 100;   //y position

                obstacleAlertDialog.show();
```

Here is the style I am using

```
    <style name="CustomDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
<!--        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>-->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

If you need more information please feel free to ask.

Thank You

Comment: try LinearLayout

Comment: the linear layout is there my custom dialog.

Comment: @ArthTilva Do you want me to remove Constraint Layout?

Comment: @Arpit Patel , Did you found the fix?

Comment: @Rajasekhar No I didn't found the solution

Comment: @ArpitPatel once try my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried with changing window attributes sizes but did not achieve what you wanted. Then I replaced your existing style `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert` with `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog`. Now this let us take control over layout.

Changed to:

```
    <style name="CustomDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

In your layout file, I removed redundant `LinearLayout`.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="#43212121"
        android:checked="true"
        android:textOff="Camera"
        android:textOn="Camera"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/two"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#43212121"
        android:checked="true"
        android:textOff="Lidar"
        android:textOn="Lidar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:background="#43212121"
        android:checked="true"
        android:textOff="Sonar"
        android:textOn="Sonar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/two"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In your java code, I am not sure if I made changes so I will just paste it.

```
private void showDialogHere() {
        
        AlertDialog.Builder obstacleDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.CustomDialog);
        obstacleDialogBuilder.setMessage(null);

        LayoutInflater inflaterObstacle = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View obstacleDialogView = inflaterObstacle.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog, null);
        obstacleDialogBuilder.setView(obstacleDialogView);

        AlertDialog obstacleAlertDialog = obstacleDialogBuilder.create();
        obstacleAlertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        Window window = obstacleAlertDialog.getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = window.getAttributes();

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;
        params.x = 100;   //x position
        params.y = 100;   //y position

        obstacleAlertDialog.show();
    }
```

Let me know if this works.

I will further try to understand why the style was not letting change the dialog size. I will post if i found anything useful.

I also found this solution working in your case [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4447449/7725103).

Comment: Thank You for answer I will check and let you know